# How to convert all daily data of a year to monthly data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

First let me tell you what I want, I want to make a chart of a growth of a users mutual funds portfolio.

Now I have a user who invests in a portfolio last year.

Now I have a task which stores all the daily growth values of a users 
portfolio in user portfolio growth table.

Now as of current date I have all daily values of a portfolio growth in my user portfolio growth table.

What I want is to show monthly growth of a users portfolio on a graph.

So, my question here is how do I convert all the daily values to monthly values from date of his investment? So, that I can show it on a graph.

UserPortfolio Schema

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: user_portfolios
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id         :integer          not null
#  portfolio_name  :string
#  amount          :integer          not null
#  investment_plan :string           not null
#  duration        :integer          default(1), not null
#  risk_level      :string           not null
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
```

UserPortfolioGrowth

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: user_portfolio_growths
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_portfolio_id :integer
#  appreciated_value :float
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#
```

Thank You!

**Edit:**
I was asked for what I had did by Tin Man:
So, this is demo of what I had tried so far.

Inititally I tried this type of code:

```
start = 10.months.ago.to_date
end_date = Date.today
(start..end_date).each do |date|
  puts date.end_of_month
end
```

for which I was getting a huge list of end dates as it itterates over all dates:

```
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
............. and so on...
```

But all I wanted was apprictaed amount of the last date of month, so basically if I am iterating over 10 months all I want is 10 values.
So, i tried to increase the index by 30 days ahead by the following logic.

```
start = 10.months.ago.to_date
end_date = Date.today
(start..end_date).each do |date|
  puts date.end_of_month
  date = date.end_of_month + 1.day
end
```

But still I am getting the following output:

```
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
2015-07-31
........................... and so on
```

I though increasing the index value might change the result but it didn't.
Please can someone suggest any solution on this?

**Edit:**
I think I found the answer, instead of itterating over a date range, I used while loop to check condition of `end_date`

This is what I did:

```
 start = 10.months.ago.to_date
    end_date = Date.today
    date_i = start
    while(date_i < end_date)
      puts date_i.end_of_month
      date_i = date_i + 1.month
    end
```

---

Output:

```
2015-07-31
2015-08-31
2015-09-30
2015-10-31
2015-11-30
2015-12-31
2016-01-31
2016-02-29
2016-03-31
2016-04-30
```

Comment: Writing an sql isn't an option? Please provide your table and model structure.

Comment: done, and  it is good even if I get last value of every month from date of the user investment to current data.

Comment: Suggested answers are ok, but you should let DB do this for your. This way you would save resources. What DB are you using?

Comment: I see lots of "What I want" and "Now" and nothing showing what you tried or evidence of effort. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is, you have to take all the values of amount or investment or whatever you want to take of a single month.

Now add them up.

and take the average.

for eg. we take for current month

```
total_amount = UserPortfolio.where(created_at: (Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)).pluck(:amount)
average_amount = total_amount.inject(0, :+)/total_amount.count
```

This will give you average for current month
similarly you are able to get for each and every month  for whole year.

Then put it in a hash or an array and Show them in graph.

Comment: this will give result of current month only

Comment: actually i didn't wanted the average but the end date amount of a month.

Comment: then just use   ( Date.today.end_of_month) instead of (Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)

Comment: hi @PraveshKhatri the problem I am getting is that we are iterating over date i.e start_date to end_date so using beginning_of_month gives all the dates from start_date..end_date, for example i am starting from 60.days.ago to date.today, then it gives all 60  having beginning_of_month date but I want on 2 values i.e two dates.

Comment: If you want, only start and end date then you can get it by, the above query is just giving you the whole range:  `UserPortfolio.where(created_at: (Date.today.beginning_of_month))`    `UserPortfolio.where(created_at: (Date.today.end_of_month))`

Comment: I tried end of month and also tried increasing index value of range to 1 month ahead , but it still gives me all sequence from start date to end date.
but all I want was only end_of_month values.  see my question edit on what I have tried so far.

Comment: Thankx for your help, Got the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> months_result = user_portfolio.user_portfolio_growths.group_by{|e| e.created_at.strftime('%B')}
> month_with_total = months_result.each{|month, data| [month, data.pluck(:appreciated_value).sum]}.to_h
#=> {"January" => 12546.00, "February" => 56487.00} something like this
```

Comment: Rather than toss out code, explain why the code is useful and what it does. The idea is to answer in a way that educates, not merely solves the immediate question.